# How to make grid cells to take up the whole space?

Tags: css, angular

Can someone suggest how to make each cells in a css grid to take up the whole space (i.e. viewport) without any overflow?

I've created a mock of the app in the following link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttxesg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.css

Or in other words how to auto-fit grid items (i.e. to take up the remaining space while stretching the whole table only to the visible viewport without any overflow)

The expected result is somewhat like this:

[image: expected result image]

```
// ignore the header part in the above image. concentrate only on the grid.
```

As you can see this will be a grid of squares of numbers (like 2 x 2 = 4, or 3 x 3 = 9, or 4 x 4 = 16, or 5 x 5 =25, etc...)

So,

condition - 1 : each cells in the grid should take the whole space.

condition - 2 : the whole table should fit to the viewport (i.e. without any overflow)

Following is what I've tried out. (seems like it is not working!)

```
:host {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Update**
You can see something similar in here. Live demo of what I'm expecting!

https://drafterleo.github.io/schulte/

Comment: [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) may be worth looking at, as it handles more dynamic layouts (2x2 to 3x3 to 4x4 ect) a bit more gracefully than what grid does

Comment: Can you please fork my stackblitz and show a demo?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are specifying a number for the grid column to have doing 'auto' for 5 times, this causes the columns not to wrap and that's why it's causing overflow.

To achieve wrapping you want to use the auto-fit or auto-fill keyword with minmax like this:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
```

These **keywords** pretty much tell the browser to handle the column sizing and if the element is too large to fit in the width then to fit it without any overflow.

The **fr** unit ensures that the space will distributed over the column that already fit and make sure you don't have any empty space at the end of the row.

The **minmax** is important because you want to specify a minimum width to make sure your column doesn't get too narrow.

Here's a good resources about this: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

And here's a stackblitz replication:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuh5kq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.css

**EDIT**: Seems like post owner wanted the grid to stretch, here's an updated stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cuh5kq

What actually solved it was adding margin: 0 and overflow: hidden to the body at styles.css and not app.css

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is wrapping as expected. But still it is not stretching cells as expected from this link: https://drafterleo.github.io/schulte/

Comment: I mean as we resize I want to avoid overflow.

Comment: So you want it to stretch to 100% of the screen?

Comment: I wanna achieve something similar to this: https://drafterleo.github.io/schulte/

Comment: As you can see above it is not leaving any empty spaces. It stretches each cells to max available height and width (thus preventing any overflow and any odd spaces)

Comment: Is it important that you do it with grid?

Comment: I just wanna achieve similar result: https://drafterleo.github.io/schulte/

Comment: Yeah I'll try to implement this now

Comment: Great! Thanks Mah.

Comment: I want to prevent overflow of the viewport, thereby fitting the whole cells within the viewport. That's alll!

Comment: I think I was manage to roughly replicate the example you sent my man :) Let me know if that helped

Comment: But this is not what I want'. This is duplicating the code for each row (in the template). What if my array is somwthing like this ? [...Array(5*5).keys()]

Comment: This would make it crazy!!

Comment: Are you talking about the angular part where I put this 5 items manually? If so I just put it there as a place holder as I thought you are more focused about the CSS.

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about that part. Where you have 5 rows.

Comment: I simplified it for example. It can be as dynamic as you want.

Comment: My array would contains numbers with an array length of square of any number. Not just [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Great effort.

Comment: At the end of the day you want to render number of rows and in each row and number of cells, so I'm not sure what you mean by go crazy. It can be as dynamic as you want.

Do you want it to work with other numbers rather than just 5?